# Express : Body undefined with post method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get data from a post request using express. But when I use Postman to create the resquest, the req.body is empty (console.log shows 'req {}')
I tried a couple of things and read similar questions in StackOverflow but I couldn't solve my issue.

Here are two screens of my Postman request using form-data and raw :
[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQYcA.png)
[postman form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB7FI.png)
For the second, I also tried with the default content-type before adding application/json

Thanks for your help !

```
// File : router.js

import express from 'express'

const router = express.Router()

// I tried some router.get routes here and it works with no problem...

router.post('/myurl', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req', req.body)
})

export default router



// File : app.js


import express from 'express';

import router from './router.js';

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use('/', router)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need three elements of the request and server side code to match.

- The `Content-Type` request header must specific the format you are sending the data in
- The request body must be encoded to match that header (and be valid)
- The server needs body parsing middleware that supports that format.

---

Your first screenshot shows you are POSTing raw data which is **invalid** JSON. It does not show what `Content-Type` request header you are including.

You need to make the JSON valid and ensure that you have `Content-Type: application/json` in the request headers.

---

Your second screenshot shows that you are posting `multipart/form-data`, but you only have middleware that parses `application/json` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

Either change the format you are POSTing in, or add suitable middleware.

Note also that the Content-Type of the individual parts is wrong. `example` is not valid JSON (`100` is valid JSON but you probably don't want it to be treated as such).

---

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations ! It is clearer, and the main error was on my first screenshot : setting "json" instead of "text" made all ok, obviously lol ! Wanted upvote your answer but have enough reputations  thanks again.